# Keep second regex lines in first regex lines matches

Tags: python, regex

I have high number of txt list files in `E:\Desktop\Linux_distro\asliiiii` directory that following is a sample of one of my files:

```
95
ROSA
139
96
Chakra
137
97
AV Linux
135
98
LibreELEC
134
99
Simplicity
131
100
Kodachi
130
20200301020449
79776361952441
```

Now I need a script that at first find `\d{14}` regex lines and after that in lines found keep only `20(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|20)[0-1][0-9]` regex lines.
This mean following result must provide to me:

```
95
ROSA
139
96
Chakra
137
97
AV Linux
135
98
LibreELEC
134
99
Simplicity
131
100
Kodachi
130
20200301020449
```

I wrote following python script but I don't know why it's not working good for my list!

```
import os
import re

def process_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    # Find lines matching \d{14}
    regex_pattern_1 = re.compile(r'\d{14}')
    matching_lines = [line.strip() for line in lines if regex_pattern_1.search(line)]

    # Keep only matches of the second regex in the found lines
    regex_pattern_2 = re.compile(r'20(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|20)[0-1][0-9]\d{8}')
    filtered_lines = []
    for line in matching_lines:
        matches = regex_pattern_2.findall(line)
        filtered_lines.extend(matches)

    # Write the filtered lines back to the file
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(filtered_lines))

def process_files_in_directory(directory_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
            process_file(file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    directory_path = r'E:\Desktop\Linux_distro\asliiiii'
    process_files_in_directory(directory_path)
    print("Processing complete.")
```

but this script provide me following result!!

```
20200301020449
```

where is this script problem?

Comment: This is not really a regex problem.  You need one loop that copies all lines until it gets to one 14 digits long.  Then, you move on to another loop that only copied lines that look like timestamps.

Comment: @TimRoberts tnq but I'm very begginer, please explain with code and script.

Comment: This is not a free coding service.  You should be able to take your own shot with that description.

Comment: @TimRoberts I didn't request free code! I provided my script in post! and only need problem of my script in answer

Comment: Can you make your example *minimal* and *meaningful* and update the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```py
matches = regex_pattern_2.findall(line[:6])
```

Or, adjust the *pattern* to incorporate the remaining *8* *characters*.

```
20(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|20)[0-1][0-9]\d{8}
```

Comment: tnq but my script only keep 20200301020449 line and remove all other lines in this post sample and i don't know where is script problem!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I mean.  Too many people reach for regexes to solve problems that don't actually require them.

```
def process_file(fn):
    fin = open(fn)
    fout = open(fn+'.out','w')

    for line in fin:
        line = line.strip()
        print(line, file=fout)
        if len(line) == 14 and line.isdigit():
            break

    for line in fin:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) == 14 and line.isdigit() and line.startswith('20'):
            print(line, file=out)

process_file('x.txt')
```

Now, I've made an assumption that checking for "14 digits starting with '20'" is good enough to find your timestamps, but you could use a regex here if you really need to find valid dates.

Note that I copy into a new file with a special name.  You can do a `delete` and `rename` at the end, if you want.

Comment: tnq sir, I edited post and tell what is problem. please read end of my post again.

Comment: Look at your first loop, producing `matching_lines`.  That loop will ONLY include lines that match your first pattern, with 14 digits.  You then loop through those lines.  You'll never get anything else.  Your approach is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Following script work good for me:

```
import os
import re

def process_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    # Keep lines that match the second regex or do not match any regex
    regex_pattern_2 = re.compile(r'20(?:0[0-9]|1[0-9]|20)[0-1][0-9]\d{8}')
    filtered_lines = [line.strip() for line in lines if regex_pattern_2.search(line) or not re.search(r'\d{14}', line)]

    # Write the filtered lines back to the file
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(filtered_lines))

def process_files_in_directory(directory_path):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, filename)
            process_file(file_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    directory_path = r'E:\Desktop\Linux_distro\asliiiii'
    process_files_in_directory(directory_path)
    print("Processing complete.")
```